# Exist or Exists?

Tags: word-choice, subject-verb-agreement

I have seen some texts where it is used **"exist"** on affirmative sentences.

I knew that for affirmative sentences with **he/she/it**, it must be used **S** at the end of the verb.

For example, a sentence that I saw in an article:

> The application needs to exist.

- Is this sentence correct? **"needs to exists"** would be incorrect?
- Wouldn't be correct **exists**, since that the person here is the application **(it)**?
- If it is not correct, can someone point a source which explains the concept?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question: "Wouldn't be correct **exists**.. ?" Are you asking if  **exists**  is correct ?  "The application need**s**  to exist."  is correct because as you say "for affirmative sentences with he/she/it, there must be an S at the end of the verb."

Comment: Hi, Laure. I made and edition on the question. I believe that now is clearer. Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your choices are

> The application needs **to exist** in the codebase.

where *to exist* is an infinitive phrase, or

> The application **exists** in the codebase.

where *exists* is the verb.

Answer (score 4):

Whether you put an *s* or *es* on the end of a verb depends on its subject and nothing else.

If a *present tense* verb's subject is a *singular third person* subject (he, she, it, etc.), *s* or *es* is used.

Any other situation, no *s* or *es* is added.  This includes the infinitive *to + {verb}*.

Exception is *to be* (use *is*) and *to have* (use *has*).