# Why does the use of "does" affect whether "exist" or "exists" is used?

Tags: verbs, do-support

I'm writing some technical documentation and came across a weird case regarding whether to use "exist" or "exists".

> Create item if it already exists.

> Create item if it doesn't already exist.

Those both read correct to me, but it feels odd one uses "exists" and the other uses "exist".  If I add "does" to the first sentence, it appears it would change "exists" to "exist":

> Create item if it does already exist.

Can someone explain to me how the word "does" is modifying the sentence, and why without it, "exists" seems to be the correct usage, but with it, "exist" appears to be correct instead?

I found https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/128807/exist-or-exists, but I still couldn't quite wrap my head around this specific usage.

Am I just wrong to begin with, or am I not understanding the difference between the two sentences?  Can I use simply "exist" in the first sentence as well, or is that grammatically incorrect?

Comment: This looks like it's at least somewhat answered by [English questions and negation with *do* in syntax](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/7594/191178), except that's not really a suitable explanation for anyone who's either a learner or just wants a simple explanation.

Comment: It's just an arbitrary rule; after "do/does/don't/doesn't" you always use the bare infinitive "exist", but in the present tense, the third person singular is "exists". I don't know what kind of explanation you want: you could get a historical one about the evolution of the present tense in English and "do" as an auxiliary verb, or a description of how conjugation and tense works in Indo-European languages and specifically Germanic ones, or a lesson on how to negate verbs in English, but the last is more suited for English Language Learners.

Comment: Your comment suffices as a valid answer to me. I assumed it wasn't an arbitrary rule and there was a more general rule being applied I simply wasn't aware of, but if it's really just a one-off case, that's fair.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do not we ask negative questions without a contraction on the not after the verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212680/why-do-not-we-ask-negative-questions-without-a-contraction-on-the-not-after-the) (John Lawler's answer, explaining do-support).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't think the question is about the contraction. It's about why we don't use the auxiliary "does" in the positive sentence.

Comment: And it's not about questions.

Comment: @Barmar I'm pointing to the comprehensive answer, not just the title question there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why update is in the present after was?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/333878/why-update-is-in-the-present-after-was)  (Answer: It's *not* - "update" is an ***infinitive***). Also [The use of do and does as an auxilliary verb?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/234275/)

Comment: Basically, English only inflects one verb form in a "compound" verb construction including "do-support", and that's ***does*** or ***doesn't*** in the examples here (and ***exist*** is an "unmarked infinitive").